# `sudo setsid command` does not spawn new process group?

Tags: sudo, session, process-groups

I am looking at a scenario where I want to run a program / command with `sudo` as part of a software test. The commands are launched from a Python script based on the `subprocess` module. I am attempting to avoid having to run the entire test suite with super user privileges.

Let's say for the purpose of this example, it's [`top`](http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2010/12/setsid-how-execute-commands-after-you-exit-shell-prompt-866/). My command starts a few sub-processes of its own and may run into a deadlock. After a timeout, I want to kill it (and its children). The obvious solution appears to be to make my command head of a new session / process group, allowing me to kill it and its children altogether at once. What I can NOT figure out is how to make this work with `sudo`. In my case, `sudo` is always password protected without exception and I want keep it this way ... if possible.

1. Works: `setsid top`
2. Works, but does NOT spawn a new process group: `sudo setsid top`
3. Problematic - hard to get the root password in in a safe and sound manner: `setsid sudo top`

I did not manage to make (3) work in a clean way. I messed around with `SUDO_ASKPASS`.

What surprised me was the fact that (2) actually runs but does NOT give me the desired new process group.

```
systemd─┬─ ...
        ├─kdeinit5─┬─ ...
        │          └─yakuake─┬─2*[bash]
        │                    ├─bash───sudo───top
        │                    ├─bash───pstree
        ...
```

Comment: Ar you looking for [`subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)?

Comment: @muru My Python process runs with normal user privileges. I know its perfectly possible to make `Popen` launch a process into a new group - there are in fact multiple ways of doing that. But all of those run into issues associated with scenario 3, i.e. SUDO_ASKPASS, when I try to run something like `subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'top'], start_new_session = True)`. I was hoping to figure out a way of starting a new session AFTER `sudo` asks for the password.

Comment: @s-m-e `sudo -b` might help (https://askubuntu.com/a/750423/158442)

Comment: @muru Yep, `sudo -b top` works, it appears to fire up a new process group. No `setsid` required. Thanks :)

Comment: @muru ``subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`` is Windows only ...

Comment: @ilkkachu Just summarized the findings in an answer :)

Comment: @s-m-e, excellent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario 2 can be fixed like this, without the use of `setsid`:

`sudo -b command`

This will create a new process group, directly below the system's init process, including the `sudo` command.

---

One word of advise, though: If one starts a process group like this with Python's `subprocess.Popen`, the resulting object's `PID` (`subprocess.Popen(...).pid`) can NOT be used for determining the `PGID` for eventual use in a pattern like `kill -9 -- -{PGID}` (it will kill the Python interpreter instead of the newly spawned process group). My workaround (requires `psutil`):

```
import os
import psutil
import subprocess

def __get_pid__(cmd_line_list):
    for pid in psutil.pids():
        proc = psutil.Process(pid)
        if cmd_line_list == proc.cmdline():
            return proc.pid
    return None

cmd = ['sudo', '-b', 'command']
cmd_proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)

print('Wrong PGID: %d' % os.getpgid(cmd_proc.pid))
print('Right PGID: %d' % os.getpgid(__get_pid__(cmd)))
```